# Getting Highcharts to render in IE 7 & 8

Tags: highcharts

I know highcharts works with IE 7 and 8, but keep getting errors.

In console, Fails on line 4287: elemStyle = element.style

http://jsfiddle.net/petercasanova/BM2Zz/

```
$(function () {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] 
        }] 
    });
  });
});
```

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working fine on IE 7 and IE 8, this may be an issue of browser-cache. Please clear cache and recheck.